# Public Page Events

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the list of public events for a public page.

I've found [/v3.0/{page-id}/events](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/), but "Only Events for which the requesting User is listed as a Host or Guest will be returned." I am neither, and it's also saying "This is a restricted edge. You cannot request access at this time."

How do I get publicly available information? Would it be easier to just parse the Facebook page website itself?

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook. i would say it´s impossible if you don´t own the page. why would you want to get events of a page you don´t own anyway?

Comment: @luschn It's not scraping, its using the API which is allowed, it is what it is meant for....

Comment: @Wobbles that was clearly meant regarding _"Would it be easier to just parse the Facebook page website itself?"_, and that is not using the API, and not allowed.

Answer (score 4):

Facebook has disabled this API due to "privacy concerns". It's not just you, they broke it for everyone.

Read more here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes/